# Problems with an overloaded function inside a Generic Function

Tags: c#

I am writing a function to help serialize data to pass through a socket.  I wanted to write a small function that would serialize one item.

```
private byte[] SerializeOne<T>(T data)
    {
        byte[] oneItem = new byte[Constants.ONE_ITEM_BUFFER];
        oneItem = BitConverter.GetBytes(data);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            oneItem.Reverse();
        return oneItem; }
```

The problem is BitConverter alwaysassumes data is a type bool and throws this error:   Argument 1 cannot convert from T to bool. Am I missing some syntax to force BitConverter to use the T type or is this not possible in C#?

Comment: you have a generic parameter but assume you always have an item_buffer. That code smells.....

Comment: `BitConverter` does not have generic method `GetBytes<T>`. Generics in C# are different from C++ templates.